# Extract specific values from raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

in QGIS 2.18.3, Windows 10, I've got a raster file in which each color defines a type of crop. See image:

[image]

Each cell value represents a type of crop. What I need to do is to extract to a new file, only the cells containing a certain value (e.g., the value 24 which corresponds to the brown cells) Ultimately, the objective is to calculate the surface of each crop within a given area.

Is there any process that can help me with this analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account that you want to calculate area per crop type:

- Reclassify your raster using raster calculator. For example, for crop 24:

  `("your_raster"  < 24)* 0 + ("your_raster" = 24)* 1`

Note that `*` means "replace by"

- Polygonize your raster (Raster -> Conversion -> Polygonize)
- Use field calculator and derive the area using the $area command (the output calculation will be based your raster's CRS)